# validations and i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a model with some validations (validates_associated, validates :numericality and validate :my_own_fn). How can I specify error messages for this validation? Of course I can add :message => :my_message in validatates and then specify my_message in locales, but can I do smth like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          email_invalid: "Email is invalid."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're almost there. Have a look at official guide on i18n [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models). According to it your message should be in a bit different place:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              invalid: "Email is invalid."
```